# Dynamic Comparison in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables, comparison

I am creating an AI for a game I am working on in AS3. For this, I need to be able to run through multiple checks to decide whether the AI performs a certain task.

I need to be able to store a comparison operator (e.g. ==) or a whole comparison (e.g. v1 == v2).

How could I store that as a variable or something to allow similar usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v1 == v2` returns an Object (a Boolean), so you can use that to store it.

As for storing an operator, that's not something (I think) any OOP language can do...

In AS3 you could recourse to the `eval` function but that would harm performance, so I suggest you implement a function that do that for you -> eg. in *poor* pseudo-code:

```
const EQUAL:int = 0;
const LESS_THAN:int = 1;
etc...

function compare(v1, v2, op):Boolean
   switch(op)
       case EQUAL
          return v1 == v2
       etc...
```

So you would use an int variable to *store your comparison operator*.

Also think to inline this function if you're compiling with ASC2.

I would also advise you to rethink your AI logic if you're planning to hardcode a lot of specific situations :S (Just ignore this bit if that's not the case).

Comment: This seems to be the best option. And I am hard coding my AI merely because its a small project. For a larger project (with a half complex AI) I would use scripting for the AI.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read about [constraint based programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming). Since we are talking AI, Prolog is the archetypal example of such programming. More technically, there exist different algorithms for solving this kind of problems, a large group of these are known as [SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem)isfiability algorithms. Here's the list of some known solvers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:SAT_solvers

Some constructs you may want to use when dealing with such problems, especially if they evolve over time: [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). By carefully modelling your situation you may avoid repeated recalculation of state. I.e. for example, if some features of the model are only activated after certain condition becomes true, then you may model it by transitioning to a state, in which the truth of this condition is implied. To give you a more concrete example, suppose you have a system, where you have a player character and the time of day. If the time of day is `night`, then the character may perform a `sleep` action, otherwise the action performed by character is `wonder around aimlessly`. You may then create states `day` and `night`, which, if entered by the game environment will both have a function `characterAction`. The game loop, when calling `characterAction()` will be unaware of the state of the environment, but the character will perform the proper action.

But it may be more beneficial to save the state of the system as, say a vector of all variables which define the state. The later scales better when you add more variables. For example, you could then define the model of your game as possible transitions from states.

Bottom line, you need to start doing something about it and ask more concrete examples when you encounter problems when implementing it. I don't think that the good solutions are limited only to what I've mentioned. Most likely they aren't.